# Remove a level of associative array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is my initial array. It includes a level for some random key like here (94475, 8868). And I want to remove these keys.

```
[
    'banner' => [
        94475 => [
            'file' => 'banners/16000555494475.jpg'
            'filename' => '16000555494475.jpg'
            'size' => 291151
            'name' => '94784.jpg'
            'ext' => 'jpg'
        ]
    ]
    'banner1' => [
        8868 => [
            'file' => 'banners/v2/1600055608868.jpg'
            'filename' => '1600055608868.jpg'
            'size' => 291151
            'name' => '94784.jpg'
            'ext' => 'jpg'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Expected output should be like this.

```
[
    'banner' => [
            'file' => 'banners/16000555494475.jpg'
            'filename' => '16000555494475.jpg'
            'size' => 291151
            'name' => '94784.jpg'
            'ext' => 'jpg'
        ]
    'banner1' => [
            'file' => 'banners/v2/1600055608868.jpg'
            'filename' => '1600055608868.jpg'
            'size' => 291151
            'name' => '94784.jpg'
            'ext' => 'jpg'
        ]
]
```

Any suggestions!

Comment: `$arr['banner1'] = $arr['banner1'][28222];`

Comment: Well thanks @shingo. What if in case I'm unaware about the key i.e 28222

Comment: If there is only 1 key, you can use `$arr['banner1'] = current($arr['banner1']);`

Comment: @shingo, I you don't mind can you please look at the updated question.

Comment: Thanks @shingo,  this `$arr['banner1'] = current($arr['banner1']);` works for me. As I was having a log array so I have used `current` method in array iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in php. In you are using php version 7 or higher you can user array_key_first instead of array_values;

```
$arr = [    
   'banner' => [
    94475 => [
        'file' => 'banners/16000555494475.jpg',
        'filename' => '16000555494475.jpg',
        'size' => 291151,
        'name' => '94784.jpg',
        'ext' => 'jpg'
    ]
],
'banner1' => [
    8868 => [
        'file' => 'banners/v2/1600055608868.jpg',
        'filename' => '1600055608868.jpg',
        'size' => 291151,
        'name' => '94784.jpg',
        'ext' => 'jpg'
    ]
] ];
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {  
   $arr[$k] = array_values($v)[0]; 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the array through a `foreach()` loop and get the initial keys `banner` and `banner1` run a nested `foreach()` loop to get the arrays. Remap those keys and values to a new array.

```
$arr = [
    'banner' => [
        94475 => [
            'file' => 'banners/16000555494475.jpg',
            'filename' => '16000555494475.jpg',
            'size' => 291151,
            'name' => '94784.jpg',
            'ext' => 'jpg'
        ]
        ],
    'banner1' => [
        8868 => [
            'file' => 'banners/v2/1600055608868.jpg',
            'filename' => '1600055608868.jpg',
            'size' => 291151,
            'name' => '94784.jpg',
            'ext' => 'jpg'
        ]
    ]
];
$newArr = []; // declare a new array
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    // the $key will be the desired key you are looking to keep
    foreach($value as $array){ 
        // map the $key and value to the newArr using the initial key and the nested $array (value)
        $newArr[$key] = $array;
    }
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

[Example php parser - 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Vrtup)

Comment: I think the second foreach loop is unnecessary as the person is trying to get the array at the first index only i.e. array at index 8868 and 94475.